# How to include dd/mm/yyyy in existing attribute in NetCDF file?

Tags: datetime, append, netcdf

I have number of Netcdf files, while converting it into text format it shows attributes named "year","lat", "lon" , "value" and "level". Now, it is showing all zeros in "year" attribute. I want to replace those zeros with dd/mm/yyyy in the netcdf file itself. where date ranges from 01/01/2003 to 31/12/2018. How to do it using any programming language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have are truly attribute, try NCO's [ncatted](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncatted), e.g.,

```
ncatted -a year,,o,c,'01/01/2003' in.nc out.nc
```

If you're trying to add values to a time variable in a CF-compliant way, then use ncap2 to modify time variable and/or units attributes.